# How to change type of line in figure in ggplot2 (with geom_step and col=strata)

Tags: r, ggplot2, cox-regression

I get the data, on this link.

```
data<- read.table('http://web1.sph.emory.edu/dkleinb/allDatasets/surv2datasets/anderson.dat', 
                  header=F, sep='', dec = '.')
library (dplyr)
data = rename(data, c(time="V1",status='V2', sex='V3', logwbc='V4', trt='V5'))
```

And I do a stratified Cox model with interaction between "trt" and "sex".

```
# Cox model, stratified by sex, with interaction trt * sex
data$trtsex <- data$trt*data$sex
fit <- coxph(Surv(time,status) ~ trt+trtsex+strata(sex), data, method='breslow')
fit
# Prediction Survival Curve (Cox model) 
newdata <- data.frame(trt=c(0,0,1,1), sex=c(0,1,0,1), trtsex=c(0,0,0,1))  
curva <- survfit(fit, newdata, conf.type = "log-log")
# And I get a dataframe (p) with strata 1-4 
library(ggfortify)
p<- fortify(curva)
```

I can plot it with ggsurvplot, (trt=0 (Tto0) with dashed line and trt=1 (Pbo1) with solid line; sex =0 (Female0) with pink colour and sex =1 (Male1) with blue colour).

```
library(survminer)
ggsurvplot(fit = curva, data, fun="pct", #fun= 'pct', 'event', 'cumhaz'
           conf.int = F,  censor = F,
           title = "Curva de Supervivencia", 
           xlab = "Time", ylab = "Prob(Sup)", 
           legend.labs = c("TTo0,Female0", "TTo0,Male1", 'Pbo1,Female0', 'Pbo1,Male1'),
           palette=c('deeppink2', 'blue', 'deeppink', 'blue'),
           linetype = c(2,2,1,1),
           size=0.6)
```

[image]

But my problem is when I try to render it with ggplot, with col=strata. How can you change the type of line in the graph so that they output "dashed" line and "solid" line, as in the graph above. With the help of stackoverlow, I was able to change the linetype in the legend, with a similar problem, but now I don't know how to change it in the figure.
Can you help me ?

```
library(ggplot2)
cols <- c("deeppink2", "blue", "deeppink2", "blue")
ggplot(p)+
  geom_step(aes(time, surv, col=strata)) +
  labs(col= '', x = "time", y = "Survival", title = "") +
  scale_color_manual(name = "TRT-Sex", values = cols, 
                     labels = paste(c("TTo0,Female0", "TTo0,Male1", "Pbo1,Female0", "Pbo1,Male1")))+
  scale_linetype_manual(name = "TRT-Sex", values=c(2,2,1,1))+
  guides(color = guide_legend(override.aes = list(linetype = c(2,2,1,1))))+
  theme_classic()+
  theme(legend.position = "right", legend.direction = "vertical") +
  theme(legend.title = element_text(family = "Courier", color = "black", size = 12,  face = 1))+
  theme(legend.text = element_text (size = 12))
```

[image]

I have been able to reproduce the image with a longer code separating the data frame (p) in 4, one for each stratum (the lengths of time and survival are different in each stratum)

```
p1<- p[p$strata==1, c('time','surv')]
p2<- p[p$strata==2, c('time','surv')]
p3<- p[p$strata==3, c('time','surv')]
p4<- p[p$strata==4, c('time','surv')]
library(ggplot2)
ggplot()+
  geom_step(aes(time, surv, col='TTo0_Female0'), lty=2, data=p1)+
  geom_step(aes(time, surv, col='TTo0_Male1'), lty=2, data=p2)+
  geom_step(aes(time, surv, col='Pbo1_Female0'), data=p3)+
  geom_step(aes(time, surv, col='Pbo1_Male1'), data=p4)+
  labs(color= 'TRT-Sex', x = "time", y = "Survival", title = "") +
  scale_color_manual(name = "TRT-Sex", values = c("TTo0_Female0" = "deeppink2", "TTo0_Male1" = "blue",
                                                  "Pbo1_Female0" = "deeppink2", "Pbo1_Male1" = "blue"))+
  scale_linetype_manual(name = "TRT-Sex", values=c(2,2,1,1))+
  guides(color = guide_legend(override.aes = list(linetype = c(2,2,1,1))))+
  theme_classic()+
  theme(legend.position = "right", legend.direction = "vertical", 
        legend.title = element_text(family = "Courier", color = "black", size = 12,  face = 1), 
        legend.text = element_text (size = 10))
```

[image]

But I would like to know if it can be done more easily and quickly with the second option (a data frame, with the 4 strata)

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You could add `linetype` in your `aes` and add `guide = 'none'` to `scale_linetype_manual` to prevent two legends like this:

```r
data<- read.table('http://web1.sph.emory.edu/dkleinb/allDatasets/surv2datasets/anderson.dat', 
                  header=FALSE, sep='', dec = '.')
library (dplyr)
data = rename(data, c(time="V1",status='V2', sex='V3', logwbc='V4', trt='V5'))

library(survival)
# Cox model, stratified by sex, with interaction trt * sex
data$trtsex <- data$trt*data$sex
fit <- coxph(Surv(time,status) ~ trt+trtsex+strata(sex), data, method='breslow')
fit
#> Call:
#> coxph(formula = Surv(time, status) ~ trt + trtsex + strata(sex), 
#>     data = data, method = "breslow")
#> 
#>          coef exp(coef) se(coef)     z      p
#> trt    0.4486    1.5661   0.5511 0.814 0.4156
#> trtsex 1.6140    5.0230   0.8322 1.939 0.0525
#> 
#> Likelihood ratio test=13.02  on 2 df, p=0.001492
#> n= 42, number of events= 30
# Prediction Survival Curve (Cox model) 
newdata <- data.frame(trt=c(0,0,1,1), sex=c(0,1,0,1), trtsex=c(0,0,0,1))  
curva <- survfit(fit, newdata, conf.type = "log-log")
# And I get a dataframe (p) with strata 1-4 
library(ggfortify)
p<- fortify(curva)

library(ggplot2)
cols <- c("deeppink2", "blue", "deeppink2", "blue")
ggplot(p)+
  geom_step(aes(time, surv, col=strata, linetype = strata)) +
  labs(col= '', x = "time", y = "Survival", title = "") +
  scale_color_manual(name = "TRT-Sex", values = cols, 
                     labels = paste(c("TTo0,Female0", "TTo0,Male1", "Pbo1,Female0", "Pbo1,Male1")))+
  scale_linetype_manual(name = "TRT-Sex", values=c(2,2,1,1), guide = 'none')+
  guides(color = guide_legend(override.aes = list(linetype = c(2,2,1,1))))+
  theme_classic()+
  theme(legend.position = "right", legend.direction = "vertical") +
  theme(legend.title = element_text(family = "Courier", color = "black", size = 12,  face = 1))+
  theme(legend.text = element_text (size = 12))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-11-22 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>